# getting numberFormatExcetion Error in validator while adding data

Tags: java, xml, spring

This is my validation.java file...
when i uploads the data and save it ther i am getting application error like **numberFormatException** ...

```
if(form.getNoOfStudents()!=null)
{

       CEBean ceBean=new CEBean();
       ceBean.put("schedulerBean", form);

       Integer count=questionsBO.getStudentList(ceBean);

       if(count<Integer.parseInt(form.getNoOfStudents()))
       {
             e.reject("errors.availableStudents", new Object[] { count }, null);

       }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the value of `form.getNoOfStudents()`. It's very likely not an integer.

Comment: number of student i added

Comment: what to do @SURESH ATTA

Comment: Please add stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Check if both `questionsBO.getStudentList(ceBean);` and `form.getNoOfStudents()` return valid integers, as probably problem is in one of these methods, most likely in the second one.

Comment: i didn't use any exception in my validation still i added but its not working..  –  sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: in BO return type is long and here integer - Tafari

Comment: For input string: ""    getting this type of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form.getNoOfStudents() return some string... Integer.parseInt() method try to parse this String to Integer. This method can throw NumberFormatException which extend RuntimeException.

So, you can do come changes in your form.getNoOfStudents() for return a valid String what can be converted in integer. Or you can try to catch exception like this

```
int parseResult = 0;
try 
{
  parseResult = Integer.parseInt(form.getNoOfStudents());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace(); // just show exception text, don't interrupt program
} 

// now if form.getNoOfStudents() was incorrect string which can't be converted to int
// parse result will be 0 and message in console, else if no errors it will contain
// valid parsed value
if(count<parseResult) 
{
   e.reject("errors.availableStudents", new Object[] { count }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some spaces or unseen characters (like `\n \t`) in the number you are trying to parse.
Try using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.strip(form.getNoOfStudents())` Before converting to an integer.